# Different Assembly Name for Each Platform Target

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I need to generate different assembly names depending on the platform target.  For example, I have a console application "bob.exe".  Instead of building for AnyCPU, I need to build explicitly for x86 and x64 and thus want "bob32.exe" and "bob64.exe".  The Application tab in Visual Studio 2010 project options disables the Platform combobox.  Build Events also don't allow options per platform so I can't rename it afterwards very easily.

**Update:**  Manually editing the project file seems to work best, no extra files are part of the build and the pdbs have a matching name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The IDE cannot handle this, but msbuild.exe does.  Edit the .csproj file with, say, Notepad.  You'll see four PropertyGroups for the settings of x86/x64 and Debug/Release.  The first one has an `<AssemblyName>` element.  Copy and paste it into the other 3 groups.  And rename their value.

Comment: This works, but beware, the build event macros do not honour it properly. You will find that the TargetName, TargetPath and TargetFileName macros have the same value regardless of the selected platform target, which is irritating. (This is with VS2012 - I haven't tried it with later versions but I suspect it will be the same as changing the behaviour of the macros between versions would break a lot of projects)

Comment: It also causes the debugger to be unable to run the program as built - you have to set Start External Program.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Post-Built event to copy the executable using the `$(PlatformName)` macro.

You'll need to copy (not rename) or the debugger won't work.

Comment: This is pretty close, but $(PlatformName) is "x86" or "x64" and I don't see an option to rename the platform.  Ideally I would like "32" and "64".  I guess I can add an extra two steps to blindly copy bobx86.exe to bob32.exe after each build.

Comment: You can go to Configuration Manager and rename the platforms.

Comment: I'm unable to rename the platforms in the project, only the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried @Hans Passant's solution but it hasn't worked in my case.

Moreover, I needed to highlight both *Configuration* and *Platform* pieces of information within the .EXE name in a scenario with four building options:

- 1) Debug, x86
- 1) Release, x86
- 1) Debug, x64
- 1) Release, x64

In order to get the desired result, I have created four XML elements *AT THE END* of the 1st `<PropertyGroup>` tag instance [the one that contains both `<ProjectGuid>` and     `<OutputType>` tags]:

```
    <AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">MyExe_Debug_x86</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">MyExe_Release_x86</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">MyExe_Debug_x64</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">MyExe_Release_x64</AssemblyName>
```

I've tested this solution on two different projects by working with VS2013 and VS2017.